# No WiFi internet

Tags: wireless, internet, connection, iwlwifi

I've been using my computer all morning today as usual. I put it on sleep and went out for a while. After 1 hour or so when I woke it up, it showed no internet. But I checked all my other devices and found out that only the Ubuntu PC had this issue. WiFi is working just fine on my phone. I'm connected to the wifi, but it shows "No internet" with a question mark. Using Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell 5559 laptops.

Some additional information that I should add here. I tried to check the internet by using my mobile hotspot and it's working just fine, the internet is working via the mobile hotspot. I have another laptop running the same Ubuntu 20.04 on which the WiFi internet is working fine. So, one thing is clear that there is no issue with my wifi or laptop hardware. My wifi and laptop just don't want to get along.

Comment: These are probably silly questions, but: (0) which version of Ubuntu are you using? (1) have you tried turning it off and on again? (2) what is the Terminal output of `rfkill list all`?

Comment: On *very* rare occasion I've experienced that, and just re-starting the networking tends to resolve it. You weren't specific as to what Ubuntu product you're using (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server, or Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop..) so restart using the appropriate method for your *unstated* product.

Comment: @guiverc Hey, I will try that. I have updated my answer to provide more information. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop.

Comment: @matigo @guiverc The problem is still there. I've tried to turn it off and on, but no effect. Output for `rfkill list all` is `phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no 2. hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no` I had to manually type it here because there is no internet in the laptop so I couldn't use this website there.